# java - how to add - every after 3rd digit of String number

Tags: java

i have contact number which i am getting from parameter which is of type String.

```
 String pharmacyPhone = "123456789";
```

here i want to add - after every 3rd digit and before 4th digit

so the output will become like `pharmacyPhone = 123-456-789.`

so how to achieve this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please include some code to show us, what you have already achieved.

Comment: even a quick google search would show you

Comment: Take a look to [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).insert(offset, char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses a regex replacement:

```
String pharmacyPhone = "123456789";
pharmacyPhone = pharmacyPhone.replaceAll("(.{3})(?=.)", "$1-");
System.out.print(pharmacyPhone);

123-456-789
```

The pattern `(.{3})(?=.)` works by matching *and* capturing three digits at a time, provided that there is at least one more digit which follows.  It then replaces with those captured three digits followed by a dash.  The positive lookahead `(?=.)` ensures that we don't add a dash at the end of the string.

Comment: Nice one. Tim got any reference for regex tut?

Comment: www.rexegg.com is a very good one.  Other than that, practice is how one generally gets good at anything; regex is no exception to this.

Comment: Indeed ack. Thanks for ref.

Comment: thanks a lot, it working as i aspected

Comment: sure..thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: what to add if we want like 123-456-7890 for the input 1234567890?

Comment: [Check the demo](https://rextester.com/HCYS38924)